# how to extract string using regex

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have the following string: `SL2.40ch12:53884872-53885197`.

I would like to assign `SL2.40ch12` to `$chromosome`, `53884872` to `$start` and `53885197` to `$end`. What's an efficient way using regular expression for doing this?

Here's how I tried doing it but my regex is off.

```
my $string = SL2.40ch12:53884872-53885197
my $chromosome =~ /^*\:$/
my $start =~ /^+d\-$/
my $end =~ /^-+d\/
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that particular string, you can do something simple like this:

```
my $string = "SL2.40ch12:53884872-53885197";
my ($chr, $start, $end) = split /[:-]/, $string, 3;
```

If you want it a little stricter, do them separately

```
my ($chr, $range) = split /:/, $string, 2;
my ($start, $end) = split /-/, $range;
```

This is, of course, assuming that you will not have colons or dashes appearing elsewhere in your data.

Comment: `[:-]` like your smiles :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that may do what you want:

```
($chromosome, $begin, $end) = /^(.*):(.*)-(.*)$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Perl, but if it uses common regexp syntax than your $start and $chromosome lines have an mistake. 
'$' - means end-of-the-line. So it will try to find dash at the end of the line.